# External accessory framework test hardware

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, external-accessory

I need to write an app for a client the uses the ExternalAccessory framework to communicate with some hardware, I read in 'External Accessory Programming Exercises' by Norman McEntire that the Simulator includes 2 test accessories, however when I run the EADemo sample app from Apple on the Simulator it says there are no accessories connected. Does anyone know how I can simulate an accessory so I can learn the framework, or is there an inexpensive piece of hardware I can use to learn with. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

true, but the redpark serial cable is an accessory itself, it comes with  its own sdk but you can use the eaframework and write your own code.

But its debatable how useful it is for learning the framework,

A lot of developers including me experiment with it using the arduino micro computer, which is a really cheap little microprocessor that is used for all kinds of hobbyist experiments.

there are two books you should look at.

Building iPhone OS Accessories: Use the iPhone Accessories API to Control and Monitor Devices
By: Ken Maskrey
Publisher: Apress
Pub. Date: June 7, 2010
Print ISBN: 978-1-4302-2931-5
Web ISBN: 1-4302-2931-4

iOS Sensor Apps with Arduino
By: Alasdair Allan
Publisher: O'Reilly Media, Inc.
Pub. Date: September 19, 2011
Print ISBN-13: 978-1-4493-0848-3

You can also look at this recent blog we authored.

http://sol3.typepad.com/tagalong_developer_journa/accessories/

Comment: i'm reading iOS Sensor Apps with Arduino, it all seems really cool however the redpark sdk does all the eaframework stuff for you so it wont help with that, but still very cool.  The Building iPhone OS Accessories books looks like it'll help alot.

Comment: hi, i wanted to know if developing hardware and mobile app that works with Redpark serial cable needs to be licensed under MFi program?

Answer (score 0):

Redpark makes a serial cable that uses the iOS Accessory framework.  Might be useful for experimentation.

Comment: looks promising, i sent them an email with some more questions I have before I drop 60 bucks

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note to your last remark.

Yes the Redpark api does all the work. But there is absolutely nothing that stops you from using the ea framework, think of the redpark sdk as a wrapper around the apple api.

Comment: i got that, but how would i use the ea framework with the redpark cable, is there documentation for that?  The only documentation i saw was using the sdk which wraps it like you said, but i wanna learn the ea framework.